# Hosting java/j2ee apps on apache tomcat6 server along with the database

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, tomcat, java

I have a java/j2ee web application built using tomcat6 and at back endI have mysql 5.1 database, I have configured my server that an amazon ec2 instance and I have installed apache tomcat6 along with mysql5.1 and also java6. I have .war file of my project. So what should I do where should I place those war files ??

Kindly help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy them to your tomcat 6 webapps directory.  Restart tomcat to deploy them unless you've got auto deployment set up.  (I don't remember which is the default(

Comment: should I copy the war file to tomcat webapp directory ?

Comment: Yes.  Then restart tomcat.